# Access Denied for LinkedIn's adAnalyticsV2 Finder Analytics API

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I am trying to connect to the LinkedIn adAnalyticsV2 Finder Analytics API.

Please may someone explain what I could possibly be doing wrong, or provide a link to the documentation that could point me in the right direction.

[image: Postman Parameters]

I have followed the documentation, which I don't fully understand, and have created the requested App and having been granted the correct permission by the account admin.

I have entered the Bearer Token and have received the below error.

I have searched for documentation that explains possible errors but cannot seem to find anything.

[image: Postman settings for API]

[image: Postman error message]

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by either missing scopes in your app's settings or you forgot to add the scopes in the OAuth configuration of Postman. Make sure your app has the permissions and your access token was created with the correct scopes. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/postman-getting-started) for more information.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are still struggling you can just renew your access token with new permission just it.
Hope work All the best

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).